# How to write a macro code to input daily SAS datasets to append them into annual datasets?

Tags: macros, sas

I have daily SAS dataset named with the following format, for example for 01/01/2012 and 01/02/2012:

daily_01jan12 and daily_02jan12

I will have to append all these datasets into an annual data set. 
What is an efficient way of writing this code using macro in SAS?

What I have right now is below. However, I would need to do it 365 times, and I am sure there must be a better way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
data libw.daily01Jan2012;
set libw.daily_01Jan2012;
Day=1;
Month=1;
Year=2012;

data libw.daily02Jan2012;
set libw.daily_02Jan2012;
Day=2;
Month=1;
Year=2012;

proc append base=libw.daily01Jan2012 data=libw.daily02Jan2012;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the datasets and the library only contains the ones you want to append then you could do something like the following:

```
data want(drop=dt);
    set libw.daily_: indsname=ds_name open=defer;

    dt = input(scan(ds_name, 2, "_"), date9.);
    day = day(dt);
    month = month(dt);
    year = year(dt);
run;
```

If you need to sort or filter the datasets first you could use proc sql to create a macro variable with all the dataset names.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select distinct catx('.', libname, memname) into :ds_list separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where
        memtype = 'DATA' and
        libname = 'LIBW' and
        memname like 'DAILY^_%' escape '^' and 
        input("01JAN2012", date9.) le input(scan(memname, 2, "_"), date9.) lt input("01JAN2013", date9.)
    order by input(scan(memname, 2, "_"), date9.);
quit;

data want(drop=dt);
    set &ds_list indsname=ds_name open=defer;

    dt = input(scan(ds_name, 2, "_"), date9.);
    day = day(dt);
    month = month(dt);
    year = year(dt);
run;
```

Comment: **N.B.** The indsname option is only available in SAS 9.2 or later. People using older versions will need to use in= along with some array processing.

Answer (score 1):

If all the datasets are in one library and they're the only ones in the folder you can do something like the following.

The colon after daily tells SAS to include all files that start with daily.

The indsname option allows you to store the file name, and then you can extract out the date part of the name.

If you need to get the day, month, year you can also extract those with the relevant functions but a single date variable is usually all you need. 
Untested:

```
data annual;
    set libw.daily: indsname=source;
    date=input(substr(source, 10, 9), date9.);
run;
```